# How do I use ffmpeg to increase the framerate of a video without affecting audio quality?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding, libav, framerate

I have a ~30k frame video at 25 fps that I'd like to make 50 fps and keep the same running time. This would probably involve duplicating every frame. However, I'd like the audio track to be unchanged. Is this possible with ffmpeg/avconv?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: All I can say is... **why**?

Comment: For greater precision in video editing. Blender VSE doesn't allow me to split audio in between frames, which I need to do sometimes in order to have, say, a word in one split rather than a word and the first little bit of the next word.

Comment: ugh, OK. Make the best of a bad job, I guess... Life would be easier with a proper video suite - but they don't come for free :/ [In which case, sorry I've no idea, but I wish you luck]

Comment: Aye to that. Running Ubuntu on a chromebook means that every other (free) software I've tried has crashed. Blender seems stable, though, so it's the one I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Basic method is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -r 50 -profile:v baseline -crf 18 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Since you're doing for editing purposes, I've set profile to baseline for quicker seek performance. CRF controls the quality/size tradeoff - lower is better but bigger.  Audio is copied over.